# Query in PHP with 'and' or 'or' as variable

Tags: php, postgresql, search, pg-query

I would like to do search for advanced search. The Search feature has and/or for every category. User can choose any combination of and n or. Here i give the screenshot

[image: Advanced Search]

I store the and/or into variable call $pil, $pil1,$pil2 and $pil3. And will put them in query. it's better than validate one by one every condition of and/or

So this is my query using postgresql in PHP

```
$query = pg_query("SELECT   evaluationdate,onlinename,channel,topik,reviewername,sourceevaluation,evaluation 
from AgentPerformance 
where onlinename like '%".$VEOn1."%'
".$pil." reviewername like '%".$VERev1."%' 
".$pil1." channel like '%".$VEChan1."%' 
".$pil2."sourceevaluation like '%".$VESource1."%'
".$pil3."evaluationdate between '".$VEStart1."' and '".$VEEnd1."'");
```

EDIT :

The problem now, All the variables must not be empty or the query will be error. any way to trick this?

Comment: may be your `$pil` or any variable will be empty. Have you checked this ?

Comment: ive try to echo them. it's not empty

Comment: try to echo the whole query

Comment: geez. that's the problem. they all must be chosen. cant be empty. i'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed some spaces near **sourceevaluation** and **evaluationdate**
Try with this query :

```
$query = pg_query("SELECT   evaluationdate,onlinename,channel,topik,reviewername,sourceevaluation,evaluation 
from AgentPerformance 
where onlinename like '%".$VEOn1."%'
".$pil." reviewername like '%".$VERev1."%' 
".$pil1." channel like '%".$VEChan1."%' 
".$pil2." sourceevaluation like '%".$VESource1."%'
".$pil3." evaluationdate between '".$VEStart1."' and '".$VEEnd1."'");
```

Comment: U re right. it helps. But the main problem hasnt been solved

Comment: I will validate them. Thank for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Simply. Use validation for each $pil whether it is empty or not. it makes me validate 4 times, but it solves the problem. The syntax error has been solved too

Comment: you can use this to verify `$pil1...$pilN` variables:
`for($i=1 ; $i<4 ; $i++) {
 if (empty(${"pil" . $i})) {
  print "pil" . $i . " is empty ";
 }
}`